# Nested "{{for}}" issue? [jsRender]

Tags: jquery, templates, jsrender

I am trying to put together a template with jsRender instead of my own version that I was on, but, I keep getting this: "Uncaught JsRender Error: Syntax error Unmatched or missing tag: "{{/for}}" in template:" followed by my entire template.

Here is a truncated version of my code, any ideas as to what is going on? Or is it just the nested for loops?

```
<div class="page" id="{{:info.id+info.name}}">
    {{for sources}}
    <header class="feed-title">
        <div class="feed-title-content">
            <span class="feed-title-text">{{:title}}</span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="scroll-left"></div>
        <div class="row-scroll">
            {{for articles}}

                          // An if, else and some standard content insertion stuff is/was here

            {{/for}}
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-right"></div>
    </section>
    {{/for}}
</div>
```

Screenshot of chrome's dev tools showing my array structure:

Screenshot 1 of an expanded view:

[image: Screenshot 1 of an expanded view]

And collapsed:

[image: And collapsed]

Any ideas as to what is going on?

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention, I am loading this from an external file using John Papa's [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975379.aspx)

**EDIT**: Demo and code:

Chrome's dev tools output of my array:

```
Object
    info: Object
    sources: Array[1]
        0: Object
            articles: Array[7]
                0: Object
                1: Object
                2: Object
                3: Object
                4: Object
                5: Object
                6: Object
            link: "http://lifehacker.com"
            title: "Lifehacker"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/3J7AE/

And of a working nested array:

```
Object
    foo: "names"
    testData: Array[2]
        0: Object
            markup: "<span style='background: yellow'>John</span>"
            name: "John"
            secondary: Array[1]
                0: Object
                1: Object
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/Vf8Bq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the jsfiddles, the issue was that tags in the section not actually shown in the code above, using {{if}} and {{else}}, didn't use the correct syntax:

They used:

```
{{for articles}}
    {{if img === false }}
        ...
    {{/if}}
    {{else}}
        ...
    {{/else}}
{{/for}}
```

instead of

```
{{for articles}}
    {{if img === false }}
        ...
    {{else}}
         ...
    {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

See this [demo sample of {{if}} and {{each}} tags](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/04_if-else-tag.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the problems seems to be your JavaScript object. I think the properties to loop over need to be arrays instead of objects. [Your template works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/6wcX8/1/) with the testdata from the jsfiddle example you gave in the comments.

If that is not it: could you add a JSON serialization of your object? Your template seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6wcX8/1/

Comment: But, I took one of John Papa's jsFiddle's and modified it to use nested loops: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/6wcX8/ and it works

Comment: That's why I posted my array structure, because I thought that might be it.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer which was wrong. Looking at the `vm` object in Chrome the main difference seems to be that `testData` and `secondary` both are arrays.

Comment: Okay, I have an each loop that gets the data and programmatically adds the information to the array/object. Then, I store it in local storage for offline use (`JSON.stringify()`). How can I redefine it so that it will work right?

Comment: Basically, I can't define it all in one shot like that, it gets created a piece at a time.

Comment: Could you show some code where you add the data to your object? I don't really get why you have problems using arrays. Serializing and deserializing an array is no problem. Initialize `obj.sources = []` and the articles property of each source as `source.articles = []`, then [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) your data into them.

Comment: I will work on it and post more code later if I can't fix it, thank you for your time and sorry, but, I need to go.